# simplexml_load_string XML error

Tags: php, xml

I was testingsimplexml_load_string() func.

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$test = stripslashes($_POST['xml']);
$testing = simplexml_load_string($test);
print_r($testing);
?>
```

After the execution following error occurred, even if i am striping slashes.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Malformed declaration expecting version in /var/www/check.php on line 5

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <?xml encoding='utf8'?><!DOCTYPE a[<!ENTITY e SYSTEM '/etc/passwd'>]><a>&e;</a> in /var/www/check.php on line 5

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /var/www/check.php on line 5

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Blank needed here in /var/www/check.php on line 5

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <?xml encoding='utf8'?><!DOCTYPE a[<!ENTITY e SYSTEM '/etc/passwd'>]><a>&e;</a> in /var/www/check.php on line 5

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /var/www/check.php on line 5

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Entity 'e' not defined in /var/www/check.php on line 5

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <?xml encoding='utf8'?><!DOCTYPE a[<!ENTITY e SYSTEM '/etc/passwd'>]><a>&e;</a> in /var/www/check.php on line 5

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /var/www/check.php on line 5
```

How i can solve this error ?

Comment: Your XML is invalid. It's possible that you've corrupted it yourself with `stripslashes()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that xml file you are trying to convert has a bad format. You can try the example that  there is in official doc [here](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.simplexml-load-string.php) in the first example and then try to fit your XML file to be like that.